# Can I print an SSRS Report using PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that I need to print from my windows form application using VS 2008 (C#). I want to print this report using PrintDocument. Is there anyway to do this? 
Here is what I have:

```
private void Printing(string pname)
{
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    if (pname.Length > 0)
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pname;

    PageSettings ps = new PageSettings();
    PaperSize pz = new PaperSize();

    pz.Height = 650;
    pz.Width = 400;
    ps.PaperSize = pz;

    printDoc.DefaultPageSettings = ps;
    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);
    printDoc.Print();
}


private void printDoc_PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{    

}
```

I just don't know how to attach the report name to the PrintDocument.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `ReportExecution2005.ReportExecutionService` and call the [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) method with the format set to "IMAGE" and [device info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155373.aspx) data set similar to:

```
<DeviceInfo>
    <OutputFormat>TIFF</OutputFormat>
</DeviceInfo>
```

The device info can be used for images to control dpi specific parameters used in print controls.